# Github workflow allow all write and read operations

Tags: github, permissions, github-actions

How do I allow all read and write operations in my github workflow job?

I've tried setting:

```
    permissions: all
    permissions: write-all|read-all
    permissions: {write-all, read-all}
    permissions: |
        write-all
        read-all
```

and many more!

I've looked into the docs but nothing more than the oprtions for read all OR write all were shown.. but no option to enable both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs);

> For each of the available scopes, shown in the table below, you can assign one of the permissions: read, write, or none. If you specify the access for any of these scopes, all of those that are not specified are set to none.

E.g. for `contents` scope, on either the whole workflow, or for a specific job;

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: write
```

Write permissions grant read permissions too, so if you are wanting to using the `write-all` *and* `read-all`, you only need to say, or;

> You can use the following syntax to define ***one of*** read-all or write-all access for all of the available scopes:
>
> `permissions: read-all`
>
> `permissions: write-all`

So you want;

```yaml
permissions: write-all
```